# php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade not works | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, change-password

I have import customers from magento 1 to magento 2 with admin tool

> System > Import

after import i run `php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade` to upgrade password_hash from md5() to sha256() but it does not works

I check on db and password_hash are not changed

Comment: You found any solution for that?